# DiffableDataSource with multiple cell types

Tags: uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit, ios13, diffabledatasource

I'm looking at DiffableDataSource available in iOS13 (or backported here: https://github.com/ra1028/DiffableDataSources) and cannot figure out how one would support multiple cell types in your collection or tableview.

Apple's sample code[1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/using_collection_view_compositional_layouts_and_diffable_data_sources) has:

```
var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, OutlineItem>! = nil
```

which seems to force a data source to be a single cell type. If I create a separate data source for another cell type - then there is no guarantee that both data sources don't have `apply` called on them at the same time - which would lead to the dreaded `NSInternalInconsistencyException` - which is familiar to anyone who has attempted to animate cell insertion/deletion manually with `performBatchUpdates`.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: did you find a better way to accomplish this one? im still struggling with the same thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

I wrapped my different data in an `enum` with associated values. In my case, my data source was of type `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>`, where `Item` was

```
enum Item: Hashable {
  case firstSection(DataModel1)
  case secondSection(DataModel2)
}
```

then in your closure passed into the data source's initialization, you get an `Item`, and you can test and unwrap the data, as needed.

(I'd add that you should ensure that your backing associated values are `Hashable`, or else you'll need to implement that. That is what the diff'ing algorithm uses to identify each cell, and resolve movements, etc)

Comment: More type safe and specific than AnyHashable: 

Comment: Can you please update the answer with the usage of this enum?

Answer (score 9):

You definitely need to have a single data source.

The key is to use a more generic type. Swift's `AnyHashable` works well here. And you just need to cast the instance of `AnyHashable` to a more specific class.

```
lazy var dataSource = CollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, AnyHashable> (collectionView: collectionView) { collectionView, indexPath, item in

        if let article = item as? Article, let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Section.articles.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ArticleCell {
            cell.article = article
            return cell
        }

        if let image = item as? ArticleImage, let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Section.trends.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ImageCell {
            cell.image = image
            return cell
        }

        fatalError()
    }
```

And the Section enum looks like this:

```
    enum Section: Int, CaseIterable {
        case articles
        case articleImages

        var cellIdentifier: String {
            switch self {
            case .articles:
                return "articleCell"
            case .articleImages:
                return "imagesCell"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this could be taking advantage your `Section` enum to identify the section with `indexPath.section`. It will be something like this:

```
lazy var dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item> (collectionView: collectionView) { collectionView, indexPath, item in

        let section = Section(rawValue: indexPath.section)
        switch section {
        case .firstSection:
             let cell = ... Your dequeue code here for first section ...
             return cell
        case .secondSection:
             let cell = ... Your dequeue code here for second section ...
             return cell
        default:
             fatalError() // Here is handling the unmapped case that should not happen
        }
    }
```